# Is there way to call PYQT checkbox-checked value into another python file .I want access value of check box into another python file

Tags: python, pyqt5

Is there way to call PYQT checkbox-checked value into another python file I want access value of check box into another python file but when I try it into another Python file its giving unchecked value and if call same thing into same python file its giving proper value.

A.py

`self.check_box = QtGui.QCheckBox('Local')
self.check_box.stateChanged.connect(b.localcal)
main_layout.addWidget(self.check_box, 2, 0, 1, 2)

## b.py

import A

def localcal():

```
check=A.check_box.isChecked()
if check == True:
    print("true")
else:
    print("false") `
```

I'm not able fetch value can someone help me.If I try same in A.py it giving proper value but in other python its show every time false vale.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a Python project with the files below, you'll get a visual representation of what you're trying to accomplish.

Alternatively, you can do this in your project:

```
self.checkNo.stateChanged.connect(self.noChecked)
self.checkYes.stateChanged.connect(self.yesChecked)
```

Connect the two buttons inside of your MainWindow class, which will call a function in another file named checkedBoxes.py

```
def yesChecked(self):
    if self.checkYes.isChecked():
        checkedBoxes.yesChecked(0)
    else:
        checkedBoxes.yesChecked(1)

def noChecked(self):
    if self.checkNo.isChecked():
        checkedBoxes.noChecked(0)
    else:
        checkedBoxes.noChecked(1)
```

main.py

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui, uic
import checkedBoxes
checkBoxesUI = uic.loadUiType(r'./ui/checkBoxes.ui')[0]
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
__appname__ = 'Checkboxes'


class CheckBoxes(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, checkBoxesUI):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(CheckBoxes, self).__init__(*args)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.checkNo.stateChanged.connect(self.noChecked)
        self.checkYes.stateChanged.connect(self.yesChecked)

    def yesChecked(self):
        if self.checkYes.isChecked():
            checkedBoxes.yesChecked(0)
        else:
            checkedBoxes.yesChecked(1)

    def noChecked(self):
        if self.checkNo.isChecked():
            checkedBoxes.noChecked(0)
        else:
            checkedBoxes.noChecked(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if os.getcwd() is False:
        sys.exit()
    else:
        cwd = os.getcwd()
        path = os.path.join(cwd, 'ui')
    if not os.path.exists(path + "\\checkBoxes.ui"):
        sys.exit()

main = CheckBoxes()
main.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

checkedBoxes.py

```
def yesChecked(state):
    if state == 0:
        print("Yes is checked!")
    else:
        print("Yes is un-checked!")


def noChecked(state):
    if state == 0:
        print("No is checked!")
    else:
        print("No is un-checked!")
```

checkBoxes.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>116</width>
    <height>152</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkYes">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Yes</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="0">
     <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkNo">
      <property name="text">
       <string>No</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>116</width>
     <height>36</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi Brennan, Thanks you so much it works now.